# Replaying an RDD in spark streaming to update an accumulator

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am actually running out of options. 
In my spark streaming application. I want to keep a state on some keys. I am getting events from Kafka. Then I extract keys from the event, say userID. When there is no events coming from Kafka I want to keep updating a counter relative to each user ID each 3 seconds, since I configured the batchduration of my StreamingContext with 3 seconds.

Now the way I am doing it might be ugly, but at least it works: I have an accumulableCollection like this:

```
val userID = ssc.sparkContext.accumulableCollection(new mutable.HashMap[String,Long]())
```

Then I create a "fake" event and keep pushing it to my spark streaming context as the following:

```
val rddQueue = new mutable.SynchronizedQueue[RDD[String]]()
for ( i <- 1 to  100) {
  rddQueue += ssc.sparkContext.makeRDD(Seq("FAKE_MESSAGE"))
  Thread.sleep(3000)
}
val inputStream = ssc.queueStream(rddQueue)

inputStream.foreachRDD( UPDATE_MY_ACCUMULATOR )
```

This would let me access to my accumulatorCollection and update all the counters of all userIDs. Up to now everything works fine, however when I change my loop from:

```
for ( i <- 1 to  100) {} #This is for test
```

To:

```
while (true) {} #This is to let me access and update my accumulator through the whole application life cycle
```

Then when I run my ./spark-submit, my application gets stuck on this stage:

```
15/12/10 18:09:00 INFO BlockManagerMasterActor: Registering block manager slave1.cluster.example:38959 with 1060.3 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(1, slave1.cluster.example, 38959)
```

Any clue on how to resolve this ? Is there a pretty straightforward way that would allow me updating the values of my userIDs (rather than creating an unuseful RDD and pushing it periodically to the queuestream)?

Answer (score 3):

The reason why the `while (true) ...` version does not work is that the control never returns to the main execution line and therefore nothing below that line gets executed. To solve that specific problem, we should execute the `while` loop in a separate thread. `Future { while () ...}` should probably work.
Also, the `Thread.sleep(3000)` when populating the `QueueDStream` in the example above is not needed. Spark Streaming will consume one message from the queue on each streaming interval.

A better way to trigger that inflow of 'tick' messages would be with the [ConstantInputDStream](https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.2/api/streaming/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ConstantInputDStream)  that plays back the same RDD at each streaming interval, therefore removing the need to create the RDD inflow with the `QueueDStream`.

That said, it looks to me that the current approach seems fragile and would need revision.